# How to add keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> bring up a browser.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is handy.

Can I set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bring up a browser (either default or specific)?