# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to show an Ubuntu Desktop notification?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, scripts, notification

What I am trying to do is, I have a few texts in a file & when I tap a key combination like ctrl+Q, the text should appear as a notification on my Ubuntu Desktop. What is the command to assign this keyboard shortcut?

Comment: O_O wat? I think you will need to develop a software to accomplish something like that.

Comment: How big would the text be? only a few lines or a text block?

Comment: Only a very few lines.

Comment: would you use *sections* (lines) or the whole file at once?

Comment: Just that line. I know how to write the script for that. But i want to execute that script using the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/notify-send.1.html) tool:

```
cd $HOME
touch foo
echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" > foo
notify-send "TEST" $(cat ~/foo)
```

it will create a notification like the one below:

[image]

Finally read [How to add keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331626/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts) to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for this notification (or better choose another combination as this one is already occupied - Thanks [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm)).

**Update**:

All you have to do now is to create a small launcher (`foo.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

notify-send "TEST" $(cat ~/foo)
```

Change its permissions:

```
chmod 777 foo.sh
```

And assign to your new shortcut the full path of your launcher:

[image]

Comment: @Anandu what's missing in my answer to satisfy your request?

Comment: I have a script to show the notification. But the script is in some other directory. So how can I set that to open with my assigned keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @AnanduMDas I've updated my answer to detail how to create the shortcut

Comment: Don't put your script in `/tmp` of course ;)