# How can I assign a keyboard shortcut for the script that I have created?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, scripts

I don't wish to open terminal each time to execute my shell script. Is it possible assign a keyboard shortcut to execute the shell script I have created?

Comment: cross question http://askubuntu.com/questions/525443/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-show-an-ubuntu-desktop-notification

Comment: Sorry for the issue.Keeping this question as it already been answered for reference to other users.

Answer (score 10):

- Go to System Settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts.
- Click on  `+` to add a custom shortcut.Name it anything.
- In the command box type `gnome-terminal -e "path_of_script"`.
  Make sure your script has executable permission.

Also if you want  your gnome-terminal should remain open after executing the script, add `read`  at  the last of your script.

Comment: Thanks. I got the same answer. But You don't really need to type the gnome-terminal stuff into the command box. Instead just specify the path. It works! :)