# Is there a global shortcut for creating strikethrough text?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gui, text, editing

Sometimes, I want to create s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶o̶u̶t̶ strikethrough text quickly and easily.  What's a quick way to do this that is usable in any program?

P.S. Someone should add 'strikethrough' as a tag for this -- I'm just not reputable enough to create a new tag.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to make this globally available:

I have a folder for stuff I install locally in my user account called `~/.local/bin`, but you don't have to put this there, you can put it wherever is most convenient.  This only affects my login.

1. Install `xsel` to enable manipulation of clipboard contents:

   ```
   sudo apt install xsel
   ```
2. Create a bash script to add strikethrough to copied text.  I call mine `strikethrough.sh`.  You can comment out one of the two lines by putting a `#` character in front of the line starting with `xsel`:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/sh
   # affects only highight/middle click
   xsel --primary | sed $"s/./&\xCC\xB6/g" | xsel --primary

   # affects only clipboard text (ctrl-c/ctrl-x and ctrl-v)
   xsel --clipboard | sed $"s/./&\xCC\xB6/g" | xsel --clipboard
   ```
3. Create a keyboard shortcut that executes the script.  I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.  If you're unfamiliar with how to do this, check out [How to add keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331626/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts)
4. Use it whenever you need strikethrough text!  Cut/Copy your text as normal, press your keyboard shortcut, then paste as normal -- V̶i̶o̶l̶a̶ Voilà!

**Credits:**

- [CommandLineFu - Add strikethrough to text](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10471/add-strikethrough-to-text)
- [AskUbuntu - A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility)