# Remap a key to the left mouse button

Tags: command-line, mouse, xmodmap, remapping

My problem is that I don't know keyname action for Mouse Click.
For example I want to remap <kbd>F1</kbd> which keycode is 67 with a mouse click 1

I have to type:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 67 = ??"
```

What I need to put in place of question marks (for mouse click)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible using only `xmodmap` tool to accomplish what you wish. This because the mouse button is not a key, so it can't have a keyname.

One way to do what you wish is to use [`xdotool` [image: Install xdotool]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool). Using the following command line you can simulate a left click of your mouse:

```
xdotool click 1
```

Now, all you have to do is to [add a custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/q/331626/147044) for the above command. You can't use the <kbd>F1</kbd> key for a custom shortcut, but you can use for example <kbd>F2</kbd> key, then use `xmodmap` to make <kbd>F1</kbd> key to act as <kbd>F2</kbd> key:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 67 = F2"
```