# Keyboard shortcut

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I very often need to change a MAC address in my job, so I would like to make two keyboard shortcuts:

1. When I press a shortcut terminal opens with pasted command

   ```
   sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) && sudo ifconfig eth0 up
   ```

   Need that cursor would appear in middle of command where I could write MAC. (or offer another command)
2. On shortcut press automatically paste from cliboard MAC address to command above and execute.

Comment: Could probably made more convenient with a small script, offering a box to enter the mac address.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Are you at it? Because if you start scripting, I don't have to go on thinking about any other solution. ;-)

Comment: @ByteCommander Please go ahead! :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Done!

Answer (score 0):

## The aim:

You want a nice little MAC changer which you can just call using a keyboard shortcut and feed it a MAC? It should also be able to read it from the clipboard?

Here is what you want:

[image: MAC Changer screenshot]

## Preparation:

To access the clipboard, we need `xsel`. Install it with the command

```bsh
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

## The scripts:

We need to make four little shell scripts to do your work.
Create the following files in `/usr/local/bin` using your favourite plain text editor. You will need sudo/root privileges to save them in the desired location.

- `get-mac`:

  ```bsh
  #! /bin/bash
  ip addr show eth0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
  ```
- `get-mac-dialog`:

  ```bsh
  #! /bin/bash
  zenity --info --title "MAC Changer" --text "Current MAC address: $(get-mac)" 2>/dev/null
  ```
- `change-mac`:

  ```bsh
  #! /bin/bash
  ifconfig eth0 down &&
  ifconfig eth0 hw ether "$@" || exit 1
  ifconfig eth0 up
  ```
- `change-mac-dialog`:

  ```bsh
  #! /bin/bash
  oldmac=$(get-mac)
  newmac=$(zenity --entry --title "MAC Changer" --text "New MAC address:" --entry-text $oldmac 2>/dev/null) &&
  gksudo change-mac $newmac || zenity --error --title "MAC Changer" --text "Failed to change MAC address"
  ```
- `paste-mac`:

  ```bsh
  #! /bin/bash
  gksudo change-mac $(xsel -ob)
  ```

If your network interface has any other name than `eth0`, you must replace all 4 occurrences of it in the scripts with the real name!

Now set the correct ownerships and permissions:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/get-mac /usr/local/bin/get-mac-dialog /usr/local/bin/change-mac /usr/local/bin/change-mac-dialog /usr/local/bin/paste-mac
sudo chown root: /usr/local/bin/get-mac /usr/local/bin/get-mac-dialog /usr/local/bin/change-mac /usr/local/bin/change-mac-dialog /usr/local/bin/paste-mac
```

## Usage summary:

- `get-mac`:

  Simply print the current MAC address of `eth0` to the terminal.
- `get-mac-dialog`:

  Show a small dialog window displaying the current MAC address of `eth0`.
- `change-mac`:

  Directly try to change the MAC address of `eth0`. It will disconnect and reconnect the interface to do this. You must run this as root!

  Example: `sudo change-mac 12:34:56:78:9a:bc`
- `change-mac-dialog`:

  Show a nice little GUI prompt asking you to enter the new MAC address (default text is the current MAC). You will be prompted for a sudo password using the GUI `gksudo`.
- `paste-mac`:

  Call `gksudo change-mac` with the current clipboard content as argument. You will be prompted for a sudo password using the GUI `gksudo`.

## Shortcuts:

I assume you can create custom shortcuts for scripts yourself, otherwise please refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/331626/367990).

Note that you should probably not create a shortcut for `change-mac` (needs to run as root and needs a MAC as argument) or `get-mac` (prints output to terminal). Use `change-mac-dialog` and `get-mac-dialog` as GUI replacement for them. `paste-mac` does neither need any input nor does it create output, so you can make a shortcut for that without any problem.