# Can selected text be wrapped in quotes/brackets?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, text-processing

Is there any way to configure that when I select text (anywhere in GUI) and then press the `"` key, the selected text do not get replaced by the quote char but instead gets wrapped in quotes char?

Where should I look for this functionality to be working? Should this be a gnome/kde? or more like a linux kernel thing?

Comment: Many IDE/text editors have this functionality.  Interested to see if this is possible system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate this functionality using the tools `xsel` and `xvkbd`. They allow you to create a shortcut that simulates typing the last selected string enclosed with double quotes.

First, install them:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel xvkbd
```

Then assign this command below to a custom keyboard shortcut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>:

```
bash -c 'xvkbd -file <(printf "\"%s\"" "$(xsel)")'
```

If you don't know how to create custom shortcuts, take a look at [How to add keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/331626/367990)